# Why isn't the Anaconda3 packages trash directory being cleared out with 'conda clean'?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I've used python on both Linux and Windows systems, and occasionally clean out things with 'conda clean --all'.

I just noticed that the anaconda3/pkgs/.trash directory on my Windows machine is on the order of 3 Gb or so.  What gives?  Why isn't this cleaned out with 'conda clean --all'?

Is it ok to just delete the things in this directory, or will it break something?

Comment: I think you can safely delete this directory. Prior versions of `conda` deleted everything except `urls.txt` in `pkgs` folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like it is a Windows issue and they are still working on it:
[fix for issue 7142](https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/7149)

In the comment: "...it should be documented that cleaning the .trash after removing env's in windows, can require manual intervention."

I removed anaconda3/pkgs/.trash directory on my PC and everything works still fine...